# Progress bar is showing 1 progress point behind than it should

Tags: swift, uikit, progress-bar, progress

I have created a progress bar, and when the user selects an option from the action sheet, the progress bar will increase according to the option selected (either 1, 3, 6 or 9 points), but there seems to be a point in delay. When I select a choice, the progress isn't affected, although when I print the state of the progress, the value goes up accurately, and then when I select another option (let's say higher points options) the progress bar gets filled by the amount of the previous selection, so it's always one step behind. I'm not sure what to do, but here is some of my code:

```swift
class StateViewController: UIViewController {
    var toNextLevel = 10
    var xpGained = 0
   
    @IBOutlet var enduranceNumber: UILabel!

// Main Progress Bars
    @IBOutlet var levelProgressBar: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet var healthProgressBar: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet var skillsProgressBar: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet var poiseProgressBar: UIProgressView!
    
    // Level Progress Bars
    @IBOutlet var enduranceProgressBar: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet var strengthProgressBar: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet var intelligenceProgressBAR: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet var flexibilityProgressBar: UIProgressView!
    
    // Skill Progress Bars
    @IBOutlet var socialProgressBar: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet var programmingProgressBar: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet var strikingProgressBar: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet var grapplingProgressBar: UIProgressView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        enduranceProgressBar.progress = Float(xpGained) / Float(toNextLevel)
        
        if enduranceProgressBar.progress == 10 {
            enduranceProgressBar.progress = 0.0
        }
        
        print("\(xpGained)")
    }
    
    func enduranceProgressEasy() {
        let percentageProgress = Float(xpGained) / Float(toNextLevel)
        enduranceProgressBar.progress = Float(percentageProgress)
        
        print("Floating")
        
        if xpGained < toNextLevel + 1 {
            xpGained += 1
            print("\(xpGained) xpGained 1")
        } else if xpGained == toNextLevel + 1 {
            enduranceProgressBar.progress = 0.0
            xpGained -= toNextLevel
        
            print("No Issues")
            switch enduranceNumber.text {
            case "1":
                enduranceProgressBar.progress = 0.0
            
                toNextLevel += 3
                enduranceNumber.text = "2"
            case "2":
                enduranceProgressBar.progress = 0.0
                xpGained = 1
           
                toNextLevel += 3
                enduranceNumber.text = "3"
            case "3":
                enduranceProgressBar.progress = 0.0
            
                xpGained = 1
                toNextLevel += 3
                enduranceNumber.text = "4"
            case "4":
                enduranceProgressBar.progress = 0.0
                xpGained = 1
                toNextLevel += 3
                enduranceNumber.text = "5"
            case "5":
                enduranceProgressBar.progress = 0.0
                xpGained = 1
                toNextLevel += 3
                enduranceNumber.text = "6"
            default:
                print("Something went wrong")
            }
        } else {
            xpGained += 1
        }
    }
    
    func enduranceProgressLight() {
        let percentageProgress = Float(xpGained) / Float(toNextLevel)
        enduranceProgressBar.progress = Float(percentageProgress)
        
        print("Floating")
        
        if xpGained < toNextLevel + 1 {
            xpGained += 3
            print("\(xpGained) xpGained 3")
        } else if xpGained == toNextLevel + 1 {
            enduranceProgressBar.progress = 0.0
            xpGained -= toNextLevel
        
            print("No Issues")
        }
    }
    
    // Create UIAlert controller in replace of UIVIEWS
    @IBAction func enduranceButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Exceed", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Easy +1", style: .default, handler: { _ in self.enduranceProgressEasy() }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Light +3", style: .default, handler: { _ in self.enduranceProgressLight() }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Hard +6", style: .default, handler: { _ in self.enduranceProgressBar.progress += 0.6 }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Intense +9", style: .default, handler: { _ in self.enduranceProgressBar.progress += 0.9 } ))
        
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil )
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure that you call progress bar updates on the main thread?

Comment: how to call progress bar updates on the main thread?

Comment: I tried to set layout options, no success unfortunately